# Reverse the order of output strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, timestamp

I have a code that creates a text box, and upon clicking the submit button, it "prints" the user input front the text box, along with a date stamp, and you can submit more input after clicking submit (it will print the new input beneath the first printed input, and so on); I want the outputs to be ordered by time (i.e. The newest post should be on the top of the page).

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<font size="5">
 <body background="images/blbkgnd.gif" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#999999" vlink="#990000" alink="#666666"> 
 <table id="table" width="700">
 <tr>
 <td> </td>
 </tr>
 <br>
 <textarea id="txtInput" style="width: 50em; height: 15em;"></textarea>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"> 

 <script> 
 function enter() { 
     var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
     var output=document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells;
     var m = new Date();
     var month = new Array();
 month[0] = "January";
 month[1] = "February";
 month[2] = "March";
 month[3] = "April";
 month[4] = "May";
 month[5] = "June";
 month[6] = "July";
 month[7] = "August";
 month[8] = "September";
 month[9] = "October";
 month[10] = "November";
 month[11] = "December";
     var monthName=month[m.getMonth()];
     var date=m.getUTCDate();
     var year= m.getUTCFullYear();

        output[0].innerHTML+="<br>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+date+" "+monthName+" "+year+"<br>"+txtInput.value+"\n";
 } 

 document.getElementById("btn").onclick = enter; 
 </script> 
 </font>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: It would be much easier to do in jQuery; you would just [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the new entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
output[0].innerHTML = date+" "
                      +monthName+" "+year+"<br>"
                      +txtInput.value
                      +"<br>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+"\n" 
                      + output[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: this just copies the first input beneath the second, i.e.

27 May 2014
test 1 


27 May 2014
test 2 


27 May 2014
test 1

Comment: @sabithpocker ... Please add some comments so that it is helpful to OP